# Удаление строк из двумерного массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив, вытащенный из диапазона таблицы A1:K500.
Строки в нем выглядят так:

```
[[02.03.2021,10:55,3,AUX-2037,450,210,240,700,,,],
 [02.03.2021,10:56,4,DAR-48,345,45,300,1035,,,],
 [02.03.2021,10:57,5,AET-2212,450,210,240,700,,,],
 [02.03.2021,10:58,6,CROX,450,210,240,700,,,],
 [02.03.2021,10:59,7,Sete-23,450,210,240,700,,,],
 [02.03.2021,12:42,8,AEG-564,450,210,240,700,,,]]
```

Так массив очень большой, а мне из него надо всего 2 типа строк, хочу отфильтровать его путем удаления ненужных строк. Вопрос - как удалить из него все строки, кроме строк, в 4 ячейке которых есть определенные записи (их два типа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основные методы массивов - переборы. Вы можете воспользоваться любым из них. Например, `filter`

```js
{
  const res = [
    ['02.03.2021', '10:55', 3, 'AUX-2037', 450, 210, 240, 700],
    ['02.03.2021', '10:56', 4, 'DAR-48', 345, 45, 300, 1035],
    ['02.03.2021', '10:57', 5, 'AET-2212', 450, 210, 240, 700],
    ['02.03.2021', '10:58', 6, 'CROX', 450, 210, 240, 700],
    ['02.03.2021', '10:59', 7, 'Sete-23', 450, 210, 240, 700],
    ['02.03.2021', '12:42', 8, 'AEG-564', 450, 210, 240, 700],
  ].filter((row) => /(aux|aeg)/.test(row[3]));
}
```

[Array.prototype.filter()](http://Array.prototype.filter())

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, отлично подошло